# Can`t edit api image in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, api

I've requested an image from this recipe api (spoonacular) and I've managed to post the pic on my site, but it's located under my background image. I know how to move and edit images but I can`t link this one in CSS so I can edit it.
Here's the .js code and the rest.
How do I address the api image in CSS?
Many noob thanks!

Tom

```js
import axios from 'axios';
const container = document.getElementById('container')
// const recipeImage = document.getElementById(`image`)

async function fetchImage() {
    try {
        const result = await axios.get('https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?apiKey=...',{
            headers:{
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }})
        const recipe = result.data;
        console.log(recipe.results[5]);
        const image = document.createElement('p')
        const title = document.createElement('h3')

        title.innerHTML =  `<h3>${recipe.results[5].title} </h3>`
        image.innerHTML = `<img src="${recipe.results[5].image}"/>`

        container.appendChild(title)
        container.appendChild(image)

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
fetchImage();
```

```css
.container{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: auto;
    left:43%;
    top: 25%;
    height: 500px;
    width: 645px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1> Jouw selectie voor vandaag . . </h1>
<header>

    <img src="../assets/mood&food%20achtergrond%20licht%20patroon.jpg" height="800" width="1695" class="background"/>
    <a href="index.html">
    <img src="../assets/mood&food logo basic.png" height="80px" width="45%" class="logo"/></a>

    <div id="container">
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
    </div>

</header>
</body>
<script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The api key needed to be refreshed. Second time this problem occurred.
Now the 'id=container' reference worked and the image was editable.